# how to execute a command everytime I open a new terminal to my server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh, tee

I am trying to capture all my session logs into a file(s) , I am using "tee" command for doing it. However I want this as a automatic behaviour for all of my new sessions. Can anyone help me to find a way so whenever I open a new window following command get auto executed ? 
Additional info : I am using putty and am already aware that session can be captured from putty to my local computer. But here I am interested in capturing it to the server itself.

```
csh -l |tee my_session_`date +%F%T`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the command to the `.bashrc` file under the user's home directory.

```
$ echo "csh -l |tee my_session_`date +%F%T`" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Commands in `.bashrc` is executed everytime a new window is spawned.

Comment: can you give me exact syntax ?

Comment: I am playing around .bashrc but not able to manage it yet.

Comment: Just run the command mentioned in the answer on the command prompt. Show how have you edited the `.bashrc` file for more details.

Comment: worked well with my requirements!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered ttyrec ?
Allows to record TTY activity in a text file.

Comment: not sure of the syntax to use it, Can you share it here ?
also I tried script command and it is also working ,but the problem with script command is that it need graceful exit to store the output to a file